# excluding rows in a data frame which matches multiple column values in another data frame

Tags: r

df1

```
   day  primer replicate count
011311     Arc        b1     0
011311    Bdnf        b1     0
011311    Bves        b1     0
011311     Crh        b1     0
011311    Egr1        b1     0
```

I have the following df1, and want to exclude rows in df2 which are equal to the df1's primer and replicate values.

df2

```
primer exptname concentrate timepoints replicate  day     realConc
Acan      0hr        55mM          0        b1 011311 0.0002771494
Acan      0hr        55mM         20        b1 011311 0.0061298654
Acan      0hr        55mM         40        b1 011311 0.0015750373
Arc       0hr        55mM          0        b1 011311 0.0010109867
Arc       0hr        55mM         20        b1 011311 0.0035939088
Arc       0hr        55mM         40        b1 011311 0.0133760938
```

So I guess my question is that I don't know how to do a 2 way match. And then exclude those values (in this case rows)

I want this

new_df

```
primer exptname concentrate timepoints replicate  day     realConc
Acan      0hr        55mM          0        b1 011311 0.0002771494
Acan      0hr        55mM         20        b1 011311 0.0061298654
Acan      0hr        55mM         40        b1 011311 0.0015750373
```

I was thinking something like:

```
new_df <- df2[!which(match(paste(df2$primer,df$replicate),paste(df1$primer,df$replicate))),]
```

obviously not working though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exclude<-!(paste(df2$primer,df2$replicate,sep='~')%in%paste(df1$primer,df1$replicate,sep='~'))
df2[exclude,]
#  primer exptname concentrate timepoints replicate   day     realConc
#1   Acan      0hr        55mM          0        b1 11311 0.0002771494
#2   Acan      0hr        55mM         20        b1 11311 0.0061298654
#3   Acan      0hr        55mM         40        b1 11311 0.0015750373
```

if you dont like to use paste you could also use

```
exclude<-!((df2$primer%in%df1$primer)&(df2$replicate%in%df1$replicate))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
  df2[ !df2$primer %in% df1$primer, ]
```

Comment: the replicates could vary though, I didn't include that in the df

Comment: whoa, sorry brother didn't mean that